# Laravel get screen height

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2

I'm using laravel + vuejs. I have a situation in which I need to have screen height in laravel/server-side. I know its easy on vuejs side but I need it in laravel side because I'm using pagination and I'm sending elements per page from laravel side. I have to know the screen size to calculate the items per page in server-side.

Thank you for the help

Comment: for pagination you need screen size .?

Answer (score 1):

You could set cookies on the client side via JS.
And read it on the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is not available to the server. Techniques used to adapt to the screen size are well developed in CSS, though.

If you really need it (for statistics?) You can send it from JavaScript to an AJAX endpoint in Laravel.